# Make Action icons appear when notification is collapsed

Tags: android, android-notifications

I currently add two actions which appear as buttons when the notification is expanded. They do not appear when the notification is collapsed as per the documentation. Some apps present the buttons when the notification is collapsed as well (see Google Play Music below). How do I make my notification do that?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_isplaying)
                .setContentTitle(nameOnly)
                .setContentText(contentText)
                .setAutoCancel(false).setWhen(0).setContentIntent(aIntent)
                .addAction(toDisplay, text, pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stop_white_36dp, context.getResources().getString(R.string.stop), sIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [MediaStyle notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.html) and use [setShowActionsInCompactView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.html#setShowActionsInCompactView(int...)) to set which actions you want to appear in the compact, unexpanded view as explained in the [Best practices in media playback talk](https://youtu.be/iIKxyDRjecU?t=1804) from I/O 2016.